# _.each loop render tablerows with button. OnClick function affecting all rows?

Tags: reactjs, lodash, web3js

I'm trying to render a table which will display a products details and have a buy button as the final column of each row. The problem is currently when I click the buy button every product in the table is bought. Any ideas?

```
var TableRows = []

_.each(this.state.productids, (value, index) => {
  TableRows.push(
    <TableRow>
      <TableRowColumn>{this.web3.toDecimal(this.state.productids[index])}</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>{this.web3.toUtf8(this.state.names[index])}</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>{this.web3.toUtf8(this.state.descriptions[index])}</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>{(this.web3.toDecimal(this.state.prices[index])) }</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>{this.state.owners[index]}</TableRowColumn>
      <RaisedButton label='Buy' onClick={this.state.productContract.buyProduct.sendTransaction(this.state.productids[index], { from: this.web3.eth.accounts[1], value:this.state.prices[index], gas:2000000 })} primary />
    </TableRow>
  )
```

Comment: you need to provide code of RaisedButton as well and `sendTransaction`

Comment: The RaisedButton is a component from material-ui http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/raised-button and sendTransaction is from web3 https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction.

Comment: then you need to pass a function to `onClick={() => this.state.productContract.buyProduct. sendTransaction ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things that I did:

1. I used the `_.map()` function instead of the `_.each()` function because it is faster and follows the React pattern of immutability.
2. You were missing a `<TableRowColumn>` element wrapping around your `<RaisedButton>` element, which is why the button was applying the `(click)` to the entire row instead of just the `<RaisedButton>` element.

```js
// Your code:
/* var TableRows = []

_.each(this.state.productids, (value, index) => {
  TableRows.push(
    <TableRow>
      <TableRowColumn>{this.web3.toDecimal(this.state.productids[index])}</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>{this.web3.toUtf8(this.state.names[index])}</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>{this.web3.toUtf8(this.state.descriptions[index])}</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>{(this.web3.toDecimal(this.state.prices[index])) }</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>{this.state.owners[index]}</TableRowColumn>
      <RaisedButton label='Buy' onClick={this.state.productContract.buyProduct.sendTransaction(this.state.productids[index], { from: this.web3.eth.accounts[1], value:this.state.prices[index], gas:2000000 })} primary />
    </TableRow>
  )*/
  
const TableRows = _.map(this.state.productids, (value, index) => {
  return <TableRow>
    <TableRowColumn>{this.web3.toDecimal(this.state.productids[index])}</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>{this.web3.toUtf8(this.state.names[index])}</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>{this.web3.toUtf8(this.state.descriptions[index])}</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>{(this.web3.toDecimal(this.state.prices[index])) }</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>{this.state.owners[index]}</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>
        <RaisedButton label='Buy' onClick={() => this.state.productContract.buyProduct.sendTransaction(this.state.productids[index], { from: this.web3.eth.accounts[1], value:this.state.prices[index], gas:2000000 })} primary />
      </TableRowColumn>
    </TableRow>
});
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks! Had to add an arrow function as @havenchyk mentioned to your code `OnClick={ () => ...`

Comment: @RaccoonPuddle => I updated my answer to include the arrow function.